# How to deploy SSR Nuxt app to Plesk web server?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, web-deployment, plesk

I am completely a noob to Nuxt.js.

I have created a nuxt.js app without any custom server such as express. I would like to upload to my web server Plesk Onyx. How do I do this?

I read few different ways that this can be done such as using docker or just deploying it directly as stated [here](https://raoulkramer.de/deploy-a-nuxt-js-application-on-a-plesk-onyx-v-server-as-node-js-application/). I don't know how to use docker so I chose that latter method and wasn't successful.

Can anyone direct me how to deploy it nuxt app correctly on a web server such Plesk Onyx?

Let me know if you require further information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have server.js file in root directory and run with plesk node

```
const express = require('express');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');

const config = require('./nuxt.config.js');

// Create new express app
const app = express();

// Listen to port 3000 or PORT env if provided
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Enable production mode
config.dev = false;

// Create instance of nuxt
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

// Add nuxt middleware
app.use(nuxt.render);

// Build on start
// new Builder(nuxt).build().catch(err => {
//   console.error(err);
//   process.exit(1);
// });
```

Answer (score -2):

**I did not check `Plesk Onyx`**

But I assume that `Plesk Onyx` gives you `VPN` with root access 
What you need to do is this

**VPN OS is ubuntu**

- access the vpn using ssh (read about putty if you like) or just ssh root@serverip
- sudo apt update
- sudo install nginx
- cd ~
- sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
- sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
- sudo apt install nodejs
- sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/nuxt_config (Search about nuxtjs nginx configration)
- sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/nuxt_config /etc/nginx/sites-enable
- sudo nginx -s reload (to reload your nginx settings)
- cd /var/www/
- mkdir nuxt-site && cd nuxt-site
- install you nuxtjs files using git clone and run npm i and npm run build if you don't have dist folder in your repo
- install pm2 (read about [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)) npm i -g pm2
- make sure that you are in the project folder and run `sudo pm2 start --name YourApplicationName npm -- start`

PS: if you push any updates in the future you should pull it and then restart or reload your pm2 like `sudo pm2 reload 0` where 0 is the index of your project in pm2 you can do `pm2 list` to see what index your project have <3